# How can I "un-cache" my memory? Or perhaps, stop the virtual memory leakage?

Tags: memory, browser, cache

Or, how can I free up all of my cached memory?

So, after just two, three days of uptime, my system's 32 GB memory is reduced to 3 GB, because the rest is all cached, AFAIK, due to my extensive browser use with loads of open tabs. I use several browsers at the same time, because they all can perform different functions, Firefox is so old it plays Youtube vids entirely commercial-free, Opera's VPN allows me access *for free* to verboten sites (pr0n, movies etc.), Chrome is CPU light, Chromium has just many historical stuff, Brave is experimental **etc. etc. **

The result is that I have to reboot every 2 or 3 days, which is annoying, and if I download stuff which takes a week to download, it gets disrupted.

This is what my memory looks like after 69 hours of uptime.
[image: Too much Memory Cached after 2 days Uptime]

But after startup, it looks like this.
[image: Memory after start up]

So, my question is:
***How do I either (A) get rid of all that cached memory, or (B) avoid that much memory being used in the first place?***

It's entirely possible I've analysed this all wrong, and that multi browser multi tab is not the cause of all that mem being cached. Please break it to me gently when you think that.
And please tell me what a solution to my problem might be.

I use Windows 10 Home, and an AMD Ryzen 5 (see pic) CPU, with 32GB installed. I don't game, and browsing is the only high mem use I employ.

EDIT:
When I close the open browsers, some memory gets released, but never ever áll of it. Eventually, I get "Windows ran out of memory, it couldn't allocate .... bytes of memory"-error messages. If I don't reboot, it crashes by itself.

EDIT2
this is what Rammap shows
[image: my ram-map]

EDIT 03

chrome-error 01 this popped up 3 times, I think its from Chromium, not regular Chrome
[image: chrome-error 01 this popped up 3 times, I think its from Chromium, not regular Chrome]

chrome-error 02  this popped up 3  times **as well**, after the 1st one
[image: chrome-error 02 this popped up 3 times as well, after the 1st one]

Here are some screenshots from RamMap. It wasn't my intention to flood or spam, I just wanted to be thorough like a Prussian.

01st tab It's a little different than from before
[image: RAMmap 01st tab It's a little different than from before]

02nd tab
[image: RAMmap 02nd tab]

03rd tab
[image: RAMmap 03rd tab]

04th tab the physical pages tab sorted by Virtual Address
[image: 04th tab the physical pages tab sorted by Virtual Address]

05th tab
[image: 05th tab]

07th tab the File Details tab sorted by Size
[image: 07th tab the File Details tab sorted by Size]

EDIT04
Best guess is now that uTorrent caused this problem. See here my uTorrent preferences. Can you give advice on how to set these, so as to NOT keep huge parts of memory **mapped** and on **standby**, which makes it not in "Unused"-status? Please answer in chat, not in comments.
[image: uTorrent preferences]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144776/discussion-on-question-by-gwenkillerby-how-can-i-un-cache-my-memory); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.